# How does 305419896 >> 28 equal 1?

Tags: bit-shift

I am learning bitwise operations and cannot figure out how 305419896 bitshifted right by 28 equals 1? Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`305419896` represented in binary is `1001000110100010101100111100` (thats 29 bits). If we take that value and shift all the bits right 28 places, we end up with just `1` (in binary and decimal).

Answer (score 2):

You can think of `>> n` as a truncated division by 2^n.

```
305419896 / 2^28 -> 305419896 / 268435456 -> 1.1377777755260468
```

The decimal part is dropped, leaving you with 1.

Of course, as andars said, the computer does this by bit shifting.
Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/absolute-beginners-guide-to-bit-shifting) for a good understanding.